# How do I keep the child menu open when loaded?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jboss, themes

we are using a pre-built admin theme called "Acme Dashboard." When the user clicks on a dropdown child and the child page loads, on the next load the menu item collapses. How can we force the menu to stay open on the next load?

A link to the theme is here:
http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0JLR295

I understand that when the child theme is loaded, the parent is given the class="active" attribute, but I don't know what to change in the CSS/JS to keep the dropdown open.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `e.stopPropagation()`

This will prevent close of any 'dropdown-menu':

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

If you want only a specific dropdown you'd change the jQuery selector `$('.dropdown-menu')` accordingly.

[**Here is a working example**](http://bootply.com/60393)