# Angular 4 Bootstrap Menu Stay Open on Page Swap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

So I am developing an Angular 4 app using a bootstrap menu. The Nav is a component that is shown in all views of the app. When you use the submenu link you get a page swap but the nav resets to the default state. I need it to remember the last state it was in or prevent the collapse from happening. I looked at examples on Stack that use jQuery, however, I am using Angular 4, so that would not be a solution for me here. Check out the other examples I have looked at for solutions:

[How do I keep the child menu open when loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474551/how-do-i-keep-the-child-menu-open-when-loaded)

[bootstrap dropdown open on pageload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495374/bootstrap-dropdown-open-on-pageload)

[Keep Bootstrap Dropdown open in Navbar no matter what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787358/keep-bootstrap-dropdown-open-in-navbar-no-matter-what)

[How to keep a submenu open when the page changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192460/how-to-keep-a-submenu-open-when-the-page-changes)

[Bootstrap toggle menu expand on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152393/bootstrap-toggle-menu-expand-on-page-load)

The one using localStorage was an interesting idea but I couldn't figure that out. Anyways here is the code I have:

nav.component.html

```
<div class="nav flex-column col-sm-3 col-md-2">
  <div class="nav-title" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave($event)">
    <div [ngClass]="search">
      <img src="../../assets/img/INEO-LOGO.svg" alt="ineo-logo" class="logo">
      <i class="fa fa-search fa-1x search-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control nav-subtext" placeholder="Search Transferee">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle clear" (click)="clear()"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a routerLink="#" class="nav-link">Transferee Dashboard</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a routerLink="#" class="nav-link">Setup</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a routerLink="#" class="nav-link">Accounting</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" (click)="toggleCollapse($event)" id="toggle">
    <a class="{{nav}}" id="tools">Tools</a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapse">
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/approvals">Approvals</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/change-auth">Change Authorization ID</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/copyfile">Copy Files</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/email">Email</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/templates">Email Templates</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/encrypt">Encryption</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/excel-import">Excel Import</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/formulas">Formulas</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/global-updates">Global Updates</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/import-export">Import Export</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/maintain-log">Maintain Log</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/preferences">Preferences</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/restore-delete-history">Restore/Delete/History</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/task-policies">Task Policies</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/ticklers">Ticklers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/unlock">Unlock Records</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-subtext">
          <a routerLink="/user-tasks">User Tasks</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a routerLink="#" class="nav-link">Reports</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a routerLink="#" class="nav-link">Custom</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a routerLink="#" class="nav-link">Tax</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a routerLink="#" class="nav-link">Lump Sum</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a routerLink="#" class="nav-link">Global Compensation</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a routerLink="#" class="nav-link">System Information</a>
  </li>
</div>
```

nav.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.scss']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  nav: string = '';
  show: boolean = false;
  search: string = 'search';

  toggleCollapse() {
    // change show
    this.show = !this.show;
    // Change style of active link
    if (this.show !== true) {
      this.nav = 'nav-link';
    } else {
      this.nav = 'nav-link-active nav-menu-active-text';
    }
  }

  mouseEnter($event) {
    this.search = $event.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'search-box' : 'search';
  }

  mouseLeave($event) {
    this.search = $event.type == 'mouseleave' ? 'search' : 'search-box';
  }

  clear() {
    let text = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i ++) {
      if(text[i].type === 'text' && text[i].value !== '') {
        text[i].value = '';
      }
    }
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Any help would be great!

Also if you provide an answer please explain it.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "page swap" do you mean the browser is actually navigating to a new page?  If so, that's probably not what you want; the whole point of angular is to create a single page application that only loads new things as needed.  (As a side effect, this means you don't have to 'remember' menu states between pages)

Comment: @Dave yes, that is what I mean. The page seems to be reloading instead of just changing views, which is not what I am looking for. to happen. I have the NAV in the app.component as a set component, but it seems to change with the change of the "page" aka view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is that the toggled list has to be outside the parent element. The problem is by clicking a submenu item the parent is refiring the toggle.

See HTML:

```
<div class="nav flex-column col-sm-3 col-md-2">
  <div class="nav-title" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave($event)">
    <div [ngClass]="search">
      <img src="../../assets/img/INEO-LOGO.svg" alt="ineo-logo" class="logo">
      <i class="fa fa-search fa-1x search-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control nav-subtext" placeholder="Search Transferee">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle clear" (click)="clear()"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a  class="nav-link">Transferee Dashboard</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a  class="nav-link">Setup</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a  class="nav-link">Accounting</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text" (click)="toggleCollapse()">
    <a [ngClass]=" show ? 'active' : ''">Tools</a>
  </li>
  <ul class="submenu" *ngIf="show">
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Approvals</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Change Authorization ID</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Copy Files</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Email</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Email Templates</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Encryption</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Excel Import</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Formulas</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Global Updates</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Import Export</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Maintain Log</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Preferences</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Restore/Delete/History</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Task Policies</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >Ticklers</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a routerLink="unlock">Unlock Records</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-subtext">
      <a >User Tasks</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a  class="nav-link">Reports</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a  class="nav-link">Custom</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a  class="nav-link">Tax</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a  class="nav-link">Lump Sum</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a  class="nav-link">Global Compensation</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu nav-text">
    <a  class="nav-link">System Information</a>
  </li>
</div>
```