# Angular 4 reloading entire application on view swap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

This is in reference to this question: [Angular 4 Bootstrap Menu Stay Open on Page Swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613630/angular-4-bootstrap-menu-stay-open-on-page-swap)

However, when doing a test component and using it the same way as the Nav component in the AppComponent, the test was being rendered 2 times. Not sure why. Anyways, the issue is that the entire app seems to be reloading or refreshing on a nav menu item being clicked. It should be just swapping the view, but it is not. Anyways here is the repo to my app:

https://github.com/trevans24/ineo-copy

I am not sure if the issue is in the module, app.component, or routing. Thanks

Comment: In your nav component try converting your routerLinks to `[routerLink]="['/route']"`

Comment: @LLai I just tried that, doesn't seem to change the issue. The routerLink is still closing the menu and swapping the view

Comment: Do you get an error when you click on the nav items? Are all of your routes defined in app-routing.module.ts?

Comment: @LLai the only component currently built is the 'Unlock' Component. The routing.module.ts defines as such for the route:

`{
    path: 'unlock',
    component: UnlockComponent
  }`

hope that helps

Comment: My guess is, when you click on a nav item and it tries to go to a route that is not defined, the app is throwing an error. Which is causing the behavior you are seeing. Maybe try adding some additional routes with some test/dummy components. Then see if the routing between the defined routes works as expected

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that the toggled list has to be outside the parent element. The problem is by clicking a submenu item the parent is refiring the toggle.